# Trying to run game Always Sometimes Monsters, unmet dependences

Tags: 14.04, games, steam

I have about 90 games on my system and they all run fine. Game Always Sometimes Monsters won't start. On Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit but I think I have the 32 bit libs (for Steam). Googling led me to dependences.sh which give me this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libsdl-mixer1.2 is already the newest version.
libsdl-mixer1.2 set to manually installed.
libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 is already the newest version.
libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-1.0-0 (>= 1.13.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev
               Depends: libgles2-mesa-dev
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Anyone else have an issue with this? I thought about going through one by one and trying to install those missing packages but I didn't want to mess anything up further.